# Ubuntu not showing progress bar while installing

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have been struggling to properly install Ubuntu. After creating all the partitions, and setting up things they way they are supposed to be set, I clicked on "Install now" and it started the process. The thing is that while is installing I can see the "Install" dialog with the different pictures, but I can't see in the bottom of the page the progress bar or console. At this point, more than 30 minutes have passed since I started to install it and I am not sure if it is actually installing and not showing anything, or its simply stuck and it wont install. 
If you guys can provide any advice, it will be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Abraham

Comment: Does unchecking Connect me to Internet help?  If so, run system update as the first step after install

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I fixed the problem. Turned out that I had not allocated enough memory for Ubuntu partitions.

Comment: Memory and partitions are two different things. Do you mean that you didn't have enough memory to partition the drive and get the progress bar? If so, it would help to make swap on the hard drive (unless you have a SSD, in which case you shouldn't EVER EVER EVER make swap) before starting ubiquity, Ubuntu's installer.

Answer (score 0):

Check in Gnome Disks and see the first partion (ex. sda1) if it's showing there are less space like (23gb free (17.6% full)) it means it's installing